# recreation time as a synonym for leisure time

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Is it natural to use "recreation time" as a synonym for leisure time.

Do you have a lot of leisure\recreation time?

Comment: see [can I say do some recreation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175152/can-i-say-do-some-recreation)

Answer (score 1):

They basically mean the same thing.
Recreation is basically a form of leisure (because you are choosing to do an activity just because you want to do it).